Youtube или Twich трансляции с питоном
Моя цель просматривать через cv2 или любую другую видео библиотеку ТРАНСЛЯЦИЮ с ютуба или твича. Мой код -
import cv2
from cap_from_youtube import cap_from_youtube

youtube_url = 'https://youtu.be/LXb3EKWsInQ'
cap = cap_from_youtube(youtube_url, '1440p60')

cv2.namedWindow('video', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

Он шикарно воспроизводит ВИДЕО с ютуба но вот проблема... Он не может воспроизвести трансляцию, просто выводит ошибку при попытке это сделать... Помогите пожалуйста ищу решение уже вторую неделю. Спасибо!
UPD: Если не возможно воспроизвести стрим с твича или ютуба посоветуйте другую БЕСПЛАТНУЮ площадку.
